# UIWebView document.getSelection() script returns nothing

Tags: uiwebview, selection

I have a UIWebView displaying string containing a locally generated sequence of Korean and Russian words. I.e. there is nothing special in the string, just simple 'body'/'span' tags to format the text.

I need to get selected text, so I use:

> NSString *selected = [articleWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getSelection()"];

This returns nothing: `NSLog (@"%@", selected);` logs out nothing.

What can be a problem here? I haven't found anyone here having similar problem and it's driving me nuts. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've got it. The following works just fine:

> NSString *selection = [articleWebView
>   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

Use this, not that.